# Qt framework: how to expose qml enum types to c++ code?

Tags: qt

I want to ask you about exposing qml enum types to c++ code.
For example:
We have a Text qml component on the scene.
Text qml component has 'style' property of enumeration type,
the value of this property can be:
    1)Text.Normal 
    2)Text.Outline
    3)Text.Raised
    4)Text.Sunken

I want to expose these enum values from qml to c++ code. How can I do this? 
I want to convert these values to string form, and want to use them in ComboBox to display users the variants of style property of the text qml component. I want that users can select  in ComboBox the concreete value of text style. Thank you.